# How would I generate an xml file with node.js and put it in a public directory on my server?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I want to take some data, update/create an xml file with it in node. Then I want to save it to a public directory.

How would I do this?

Comment: I need to give rss readers something to munch on bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently [13 XML modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-parsers-xml) for Node.js listed at the modules directory.  Surely one of those is sufficient to your needs.  Some are SAX, some are DOM, some are both; some are just parsers, others have generation capability; some are synchronous and others asynchronous.  Something there has to work for you, if only `libxmljs`'s full capabilities.